# Are there any cloud libraries that takes EC2 inputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, virtualization

This might seem like a somewhat strange question, but are there any cloud libraries (jClouds, libclouds etc) that can take EC2 commands and port them to other clouds?

The idea is basically to enable a company with a native EC2 integration to move to a different cloud provider without having to rewrite the provisioning code.

Comment: The most easily transferable part would be provisioning that happens within an instance (chef, puppet, etc). Outside of this, its very difficult to make each platform interchangeable. Between varying features, best practices, different APIs, what you may do within one platform, may not transfer the same way to another platform.

Comment: Have you looked at opestack and it's EC2 compatibility API? More info at: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Nova/APIFeatureComparison

Comment: Unfortunately either solutions solves the problem. The idea is as follows:
EC2 API -> Abstraction Layer -> Cloud provider supported by abstraction layer

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use a service such as [Ravello](http://www.ravellosystems.com/), which supports multiple public clouds for deployment.

The user interacts with the Ravello API/UI, and Ravello handles the interaction with the various cloud APIs.